# What is the usage of 'confidence' and 'lift' concepts of Apriori algorithm

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, data-mining, apriori

I am going to implement a personal recommendation system using Apriori algorithm.
I know there are three useful concepts as 'support',confidence' and 'lift. I already know the meaning of them. Also I know how to find the frequent item sets using support concept. But I wonder why confidence and lift concepts are there for if we can find frequent item sets using support rule?

could you explain me why 'confidence' and 'lift' concepts are there when 'support' concept is already applied and how can I proceed with 'confidence' and 'lift' concepts if I have already used support concept for the data set?

I would be highly obliged if you could answer with SQL queries since I am still an undergraduate. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Support alone yields many redundant rules.

e.g.

```
A -> B
A, C -> B
A, D -> B
A, E -> B
...
```

The purpose of lift and similar measures is to remove complex rules that are not much better than the simple rule.
In above case, the simple rule A -> B may have less confidence than the complex rules, but much more support. The other rules may be just coincidence of this strong pattern, with a marginally stronger confidence because of the smaller sample size.

Similarly, if you have:

```
A -> B  confidence: 90%
C -> D  confidence: 90%
A, C -> B, D confidence: 80%
```

then the last rule is even *bad*, despite the high confidence!
The first two rules yield the same outcome, but with higher confidence. So that last rule shouldn't be 80% correct, but -10%  correct if you assume the first two rules to hold!

Thus, support and confidence are *not* enough to consider.